# SpreadsheetGear CopyFromDataTable cell formatting

Tags: c#, excel, formatting, spreadsheetgear

I'm trying to export data from a DataTable into an Excel file using SpreadsheetGear. The worksheet in the Excel file will be copied from a template with column headers and specific formatting. For ease of maintenance (change a stored proc and the template to change report content, rather than redeploy a service) I don't want to do certain column formatting in code, namely column fill colors.

I use SpreadsheetGear's [CopyFromDataTable](http://www.spreadsheetgear.com/support/help/spreadsheetgear.net.3.0/SpreadsheetGear~SpreadsheetGear.IRange~CopyFromDataTable.html) to do the export. However, the InsertCells flag does not cause the data to take on the format (column fill colors) of the rows it's inserted in as the description notes ("This allows the cells to be preformatted").

I'm working around this by not using the InsertCells flag and instead just setting the column fill colors on the entire columns in the template. However, this causes the entire column to be colored, including beyond the used range. I want to limit the formatting to the used range.

Is there some way to clear any formatting *outside* of the UsedRange? As I'm writing this I'm realizing this approach is convoluted. But the formatting is mandatory and I want to simplify maintenance to only require a stored proc change and template change. I'm open to any other approach there might be to facilitate that.

Comment: To clarify - Is the number of columns and rows in the table indeterminate? Otherwise, if there is always a fixed number of columns and rows you can preset the formatting of the target area in the sheet template.

Comment: @Xcheque - The number of columns is known and they are preformatted in the template, it's only the rows (indeterminate amount) that are the problem. I don't want to format the columns past the used amount of rows, which happens if I set the fill color on the entire column in the template. I can't get the SpreadsheetGear insert to behave like a manual insert in Excel where the inserted row takes the format of what it's inserted above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [SetDataFlags](http://www.spreadsheetgear.com/support/help/spreadsheetgear.net.7.0/#SpreadsheetGear2012~SpreadsheetGear.Data.SetDataFlags.html).InserCells enum option should allow for formatting to be picked up in the range populated only by your DataTable.  However, there are exact requirements to make this work properly, as stated in the [documentation](http://www.spreadsheetgear.com/support/help/spreadsheetgear.net.7.0/#SpreadsheetGear2012.Core~SpreadsheetGear.IRange~CopyFromDataTable.html):

*"When specifying this flag [InsertCells], you must provide a range with exactly two rows for data, preceded by a row for column headers if SpreadsheetGear.Data.SetDataFlags.NoColumnHeaders is not specified."*

The "two rows for data" should be formatted however you require (interior/fill color, etc).  The Explorer Samples Solutions that came with SpreadsheetGear (found in the SpreadsheetGear folder in your Start Menu/Screen) includes a sample that demonstrates this, under *Reporting > DataSet to Workbook*.

**UPDATE**

Below is an example that demonstrates how to use the InsertCells flag in combination with NoColumnHeaders.  This code assumes you have a `worksheet` already setup with the formatted range and that you can obtain a DataTable whose size corresponds to the number of columns in your formatted range.

```
using SpreadsheetGear;
using SpreadsheetGear.Data;

// Generate DataTable.  For this example, let's say it is 5 columns wide and 
// 10 rows deep...
DataTable dataTable = // ...get DataTable...

// We're not interested in a "Column Header" row, so for the above dataTable, 
// an IRange 5 columns wide and 2 rows deep needs to be specified where those
// two rows are already setup with the desired formatting.  In this case B2:F3
// are formatted accordingly.
worksheet.Cells["B2:F3"].CopyFromDataTable(dataTable, SetDataFlags.InsertCells |
    SetDataFlags.NoColumnHeaders);

// Sheet should how have B2:F11 populated with your dataTable data, with all
// rows having picked up the formatting as originally specified in B2:F3
```

Comment: Yes, I read through this. The documentation was a little confusing because, as far as I can tell, you can't specify a second data flag. So you can't set NoColumnHeaders if you're setting InsertCells, or vice versa (please correct me if I'm wrong). Aside from that, though, this was exactly the approach I took and it didn't work as desired. It acted like pasting values - the data was just laid over whatever formats cells already had.

Comment: It is possible to use multiple flags.  You just need to use the bitwise OR operator (|) to combine them.  Regarding your overall problem with this feature, I am not aware of any issues with InsertCells, and I work for SpreadsheetGear so I should know!  I'll revise my answer with an example that demonstrates this feature, in case it helps.

Comment: Interesting, I knew I needed to learn bitwise operators sooner or later! I'll try this out and see what happens.

Comment: @CsabaToth, yes, thanks for asking so I remembered to mark my answer.

Answer (score 1):

I have two suggestions

1) Not very elegant but you could use conditional formatting in the Excel Template for the maximum number of rows that you expect to populate the spreadsheet. You should be able to switch on the desired format if the cell is not blank or if some other reference cell in the same row meets a defined criteria.

2) Use Datatable.Rows.Count to count the number of rows in your C# datatable then construct an Excel cell range definition from that information. Apply the desired formatting to the target cell range after pasting in the table (sorry no time for code examples).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. With 1) - the row count isn't very predictable. But maybe I could conditionally format every single row (it's .xls so not too awful), then after copying the data in, copy and paste the entire sheet over itself to remove the conditional formatting (is there a formatting "paste values" equivalent?) then delete all the blank lines. With 2) - I'm doing this with the original implementation but I don't want the code to do any formatting (to avoid redeployment). Maybe I can avoid all this and just get the users to be okay with column formatting beyond the used range...